# Remove parent page from URL without plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

On certain pages I'm looking to remove the parent page from the URL.

So instead of:
example.com/parent-page/child-page

I'd like it to display:
example.com/child-page

I have tried the following method but no luck:

```
function wpse_101072_flatten_hierarchies( $post_link, $post ) {
    if ( 'page' != $post->post_type )
        return $post_link;

    $uri = '';
    foreach ( $post->ancestors as $parent ) {
        $uri = get_post( $parent )->post_name . "/" . $uri;
    }

    return str_replace( $uri, '', $post_link );
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpse_101072_flatten_hierarchies', 10, 2 );
```

Is there any known solution that works without a plugin?

Comment: you can try htaccess

Comment: I could but I'm trying to put this into a plugin to reuse for myself